# Scala: Parallel assignment of Tuples

Tags: scala, tuples, iterable-unpacking

Is it possible to assign tuple members in parallel in Scala. if not is there another technique to accomplish something similar?

```
val players = List(
    new Player("Django Reinhardt", 42), 
    new Player("Sol Hoopii", 57),
    new Player("Marc Ribot", 64)
)

val winners, losers = players.partition(p => p.score > 50)

// winners = List(Player name:Sol Hoopii score: 57, Player name:Marc Ribot score: 64)
// losers = List(Player name:Django Reinhardt score: 42)
```

Comment: if you didnt know you can use the short hand notation: players.partition(_.score > 50)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
val winners, losers = players.partition(p => p.score > 50)
```

Assignes the (List, List) tuple to two variables. If you want to unpack the tuple you have to use

```
val (winners, losers) = players.partition(p => p.score > 50)
```

Which does exactly what you want. :-)

Comment: +1 for pointing out what the syntax without parenthesis means. Or, rather, if I _could_ award one additional vote, I would. :-)

Comment: I suggest, though, that you also point out the tuple assignment works because it is actually a pattern matching.

Comment: I would be certainly be interested in the pattern matching example